# Add column in power pivot from other table

Tags: excel, pivot, pivot-table, powerpivot

I am a new in power pivot,I have two tables the first one conatins article, price, taxe, total and the second has columns article, type and other information. So for me i want the columns taxe to be in the table two ( like vlookup ). Pleaze help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a relationship between the two tables with the `article` field as the key. Then you can use the `tax` field in a pivot table without adding it to the second data table.

[image]

[image]